# How exactly are WeakReferences processed?

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection

I looked at the `WeakReference` source code. Here it is:

```java
public class WeakReference<T> extends Reference<T> {

    public WeakReference(T referent) {
        super(referent);
    }

    public WeakReference(T referent, ReferenceQueue<? super T> q) {
        super(referent, q);
    }

}
```

As you can see, it contains nothing save for a couple of constructors. I looked into [the JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/jvms17.pdf). It contains no mention of "weak references" except for

> Classes that might require special support from the Java Virtual Machine include
> those that support:
>
> [...]
>
> • Weak references, such as the classes in the package java.lang.ref.

Do JVM implementations implement that functionality as they see fit then (or, alternatively, not implement it at all)? I tried to test that theory and visited [Hotspot's page](https://openjdk.org/groups/hotspot/). Unfortunately, it lacks adequate documentation and its [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/hotspot) is too complex for me to analyze

All in all, how do `WeakReference`s work? What is the corresponding logic that results in a different garbage collector behavior?

Comment: The [javadoc on WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) explains what it does and why pretty well. I wouldn't worry about the exact implementation, especially if digging through JVM code feels complex.

Comment: @Jorn where does that logic relating to weak reference handling exist? Do JVM implementations implement it however they like? It's not a cross-platform feature then, is it?

Comment: Yes, JVMs can implement it as they choose. They have to, as different JVMs can have completely different garbage collector implementations. It's still cross-platform, since the spec requires those implementations to follow certain rules. The implementation may not be the exact same, but the effect is the same.

Comment: @Jorn the spec says nothing imperative on weak references (see the question). It seems it's entirely legal for JVM makers not to handle them in any special way at all

Comment: What are you worried about exactly? A JVM just choosing not to properly handle weak references? I don't think that particular JVM would see much use.

Comment: @Jorn but does it make one a good Java programmer if they rely on JVM-specific functionality?

Comment: I give up......

Answer (score 2):

> All in all, how do WeakReferences work?

They're part of the garbage collector analyzing reachability of references from GC roots and treating the `Reference` types specially. In the case of `WeakReference` they do it by not traversing the referent field as part of liveness checking.

How exactly they do that is indeed an implementation detail. Of course the observable behavior must still be in bounds of what's allowed by the spec and the JDK documentation.

> Do JVM implementations implement that functionality as they see fit then (or, alternatively, not implement it at all)?

Yes. GCs are not guaranteed to run, ever. Which means weak reference processing may also never happen.

[EpsilonGC](https://openjdk.org/jeps/318) is such a GC.

Comment: But those bounds are not defined in the spec, are they?

Comment: @JoreJoh what bounds do you mean?

Comment: @JoreJoh the whole spec is the bounds. E.g. the weak ref getting nulled must be consistent with the JMM.